# Add current changes view to the home screen?

Tags: git, git-extensions

How can I add a view of current files state (modifications, staged files, etc) to the home screen of Git Extensions?

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Git Extensions -> Performance

[x] Show current working directory changes in revision graph (slow!)